# finding overlap using GenomicRanges with two data sets specifying minoverlap Function

Tags: r, range, bioinformatics, overlap, genomicranges

I am trying to find overlap using GenomicRanges package function findOverlaps,I have two data sets and want to find overlaps using `minoverlap`  parameter. So I want to give different `minoverlap`  for every read.

Ex df1:

```
chr2 2800 3270
chr2 3600 4152
chr2 3719 5092
chr2 3893 4547
```

Ex.  df2 :

```
chr2 263 20091
chr2 342 17222
chr2 414 2612
chr2 846 4265
chr2L 1030 11575
```

I want to find overlaps by giving different values of the minOverlap parameter,I have tried something like this but didn't work. The desired output is as usual in genomicRange object.

```
Example Output:
Hits object with 2 hits and 0 metadata columns:
      queryHits subjectHits
      <integer>   <integer>
  [1]         1           1
  [2]         1           2
  -------
  queryLength: 1 / subjectLength: 10
```

```
df11<-toGRanges(df1)
df22<-toGRanges(df2)

minOv<-mapply("-", df1$V3,df1$V2)+1

for (j in minOv) {
    ff<-findOverlaps(query = df11,subject = df22,minoverlap = j)
}
```

Edit ::

```
df1::
structure(list(df1c = c("chr2", "chr2", "chr2", "chr2"), df1c2 = c(2800, 
3600, 3719, 3893), df1c3 = c(3270, 4152, 5092, 4547)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))

df2::

structure(list(df1c = c("chr2", "chr2", "chr2", "chr2", "chr2L"
), df1c2 = c(263, 342, 424, 846, 1030), df1c3 = c(20091, 17222, 
2612, 4265, 11575)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: It would help if you `dput(df1)` and `dput(df2)` above in as your example data pasting in their `structure(...)` s.

Comment: hi Chris, just added the dput of df1 df2

Comment: These would be subject to yet a little more processing as their signatures `## S4 method for signature 'GenomicRanges,GenomicRanges'
     findOverlaps(query, subject,` that would be also stated in the `structure(...)`, would be GenomicRanges  rather than data.frame(s), see ?GenomicRanges::findOverlaps. And welcome to Stackoverflow.

Comment: Just demonstrating I  know nothing of the problem at hand `GRanges::makeGRangesFromDataFrame(df1)`.

Comment: the thing i sthat along with that I also want to use minoverlap parameter in finOverlap function. by default it allows only single number but I want to give different value for different read to findOverlap

Comment: Prior to any processing, you have to arrive at a GenomicRanges object, that you will need, and anyone working along would need, and not the currrent df1, df2, that may be nearly correct as to structure, but are incorrect as to `names` and other data, as required by`GenomicRanges::makeGRangesFromDataFrame`.